# 2N5160 RF transistor

Tags: transistors

I'm new to high frequency testing, but I am redesigning an old circuit which uses a bipolar Motorola 2N5160.  The specification sheet says that at a Power In is  400 MHz, 28 volts, PNP transistor, 0.16 watts in. I should get 1 watt out min. or 1.25 watts typically.

I built the test circuit in the spec sheet that Motorola claims is the 400 MHz Test Circuit and I don't get 1.25 watts out. For my Power Out, I get about 0.15 watts power out at 175 MHz and 0 at 400 MHz. I've rechecked all the components on the test board that Motorola used, and circuit is properly grounded. My Gain Bandwidth Product out is barely 9 dB. Any ideas why output is so low at 175 Mhz?

The transistor I'm testing was made by Motorola and is a know good working device in the current application circuit, in which I desoldered the transistor from.  When I apply 400 MHz, the transistor oscillates wildly and gets very hot. Only after I tune the capacitors do I get 9 dB out at 175 MHz. I'm trying to migrate to a surface mount design. My question is about the 400 MHz test schematic. Could the test schematic be wrong? The 2N5160 was a very popular transistor for decades. Was the 2N5160 transistor ever a 400 MHz transistor?  Am I interpreting test circuit incorrectly?

Comment: What about a circuit diagram? Is it the one on page 2 of this: http://www.gigatechnik.hu/pdf/2N5160.pdf? If so what supply voltage did you use?

Comment: My input voltage is 28 volts .

Comment: Positive or negative?

Comment: @user3078097 . the base inductor to ground, shown in the fixture schematic back then was wound upon a lossy ferrite. Keeping the Q of the coil low as suggested in the data sheet schematic. We had a lot of self regeneration (oscillating and heating) if the Q wasn't low.